# How to replace .html with forward slash in BrowserSync?

Tags: browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I am developing website using BrowserSync. However, in the production version, I will be replacing .html with forward slash via .htaccess . Is it possible to achive the same result using BrowserSync?

Answer (score 0):

You can start your browsersync with next server config:

```
server: {
    baseDir: "./build",
    serveStaticOptions: {
        extensions: ['html']
    },
    middleware: function(req, res, next) {
        var url = req.url;

        if (url.length > 1 && url[url.length-1] === "/") {
            req.url = url.slice(0, url.length - 1);
        }

        return next();
    }
}
```

Not perfect solution, but if you go to http://foo/bar/ instead http://foo/bar.html it will not cause get error.